# Facebook access token issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I have created the access token for my facebook app. i have two token one is for app and another one is for app test user. when i try to get some post info by hit the facebook graph api using app access token, I am getting the response, but when i use test user access token it gives graph exception.

The url looks like this... i tried the same url with app and test user access token.

https://graph.facebook.com/746574638_7468765477651?fields=created_time&access_token=CAGy9XKP2........

both token have extended (insight and read_stream) permission...

Anybody know why this happening?